# Is accepting XML and responding with JSON switching protocol?

Tags: json, xml, network-protocols

I would just like to know if accepting an XML message that is then responded to with a JSON message is protocol switching as I understand that neither of these are even examples of protocols, therefor could be using the same protocol incoming and outgoing and wouldnt need to switch?

Comment: This sounds like a semantic argument in which the only thing that matters is that the person you are communicating with understands what you mean and thus can't be reasonably answered on Stackoverflow.

Comment: In terms of the OSI reference model, XML and JSON can best be regarded as layer 6 protocols. As far as I'm aware, in an internet context the term protocol switching usually refers to switching at layer 3.